# How to fix Jquery UI slider, Showing Negative value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

[image]
The Jquery UI Slider Sometimes showing `-1` value in **firefox 10.0.2** How to fix this ?

The problem is in the demo of the orginal plugin site [jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html)

Comment: where exactly does this happen ? and why is it a problem ?

Comment: Im not able to reproduce this...

Comment: shouldnt show -1, it should start from 0 only

Comment: Seems like this issue is in windows/Firefox 10 only

Comment: what version jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: the problem is in the demo of the orginal plugin site http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html

Comment: yes I am able to reproduce it in Windows Firefox 10.0.2 .. its happening when you move the slider very slowly!!!

Comment: @Nikhil no you can reproduce in GNU/Linux too . Check very slowly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug with jQuery UI library.. others also reported it with version 1.8.16.. You can see it here http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8108

As per the comments in the thread I have checked it with 1.8.17 and its working great.. so seems like the bug got re introduced in 1.8.18..

Try changing the files to version 1.8.17.. it should work!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this when working with Firefox 10.0.2 for OS X, and found that it existed for jQuery UI 1.8.16, 1.8.17 and 1.8.18, so unfortunately Anz's solution didn't work for me.

I made a really simply patch-job of it in the meantime, by simply going to function I use to update the sliders' labels' and rewriting it:

```
function SlideFunction(sSlider, ui) {
    if (ui.value == -1) {
        ui.value = 0;
    };
    $(sSlider).val(ui.value);
};
```

Where sSlider is a local string variable that contains the ID of the slider being moved.

Answer (score -2):

If its a problem that you're getting reguly why not try applying a patch, like the following:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      checkValues(ui.values[ 0 ], ui.values[ 1 ]);
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

  function checkValues(valOne, valTwo){
    if (valOne == -1){
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$0 - $" + valTwo );
      $('.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
    }
  };
});
```

It's a bit of a crude patch, but it does the trick. I've tested it here - http://www.alsdev.co.uk/slider. NOTE I've tested it using 10 as the check, as I cant reproduce the '-1'.

Hope this helps you out a little.

Comment: i checked in firefox 10 but still have the same problem

Comment: does it not set the value to 0; when you get to -1?

Comment: Yes some times the value is going to 1 to -1 .the funny thing is that when firebug is open it doesn't show the error